# Create new Tkinter window with new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm attempting to create a Tkinter GUI that runs the mainloop in its own thread, enabling me to run things in other threads (which potentially involves updating elements in the Tkinter GUI). I have the construct below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

class DisplayWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.running = False
        self.root.destroy()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.callback)
        self.root.geometry('600x600')

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Hello World').pack()

        self.root.mainloop()
```

I can do something like the following with this

```
win = DisplayWindow()
win.start()
```

My understanding of how this works is that when `win.start()` is called the first time, a new thread is created, set to run the `run` method, and the thread is started. This thread executes the creation of a Tkinter GUI that runs the mainloop until the window is closed (at which time the thread should become inactive). If I close the window and call `win.start()` again, I expect that the second call should just repeat the process, creating a new thread that calls the `run` method. However, calling `start` a second time simply crashes python.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tkinter doesn't like it when it starts in another thread, nor when you try to make a `tk.Tk()` instance more then once.

Comment: do you really need to handle the threads yourself or could you do `self.root.after(0,TASK)` to simply handle the different tasks that need to be done

Comment: I've tried using the `after` method and that just doesn't seem to work for me. If you want, I can try to post a short snippet of the `after` code I've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: *which potentially involves updating elements in the Tkinter GUI*: your expectations are too high: that is simply  impossible to do.

Comment: Well, I can update the GUI the first time it is run. My issue comes when I try to rerun the GUI. This problem appears to be a major failure of the Tkinter module and python in general. I'm really struggling to have flexible GUIs in python.

Comment: @BEGUERADJ you have a very loose definition of _impossible_.  `import tkinter; help(tkinter.Widget.update)` and @zephyr when I run your code on my mac it doesn't work at all, I can verify that the thread does get to `self.root.mainloop()` but the window never opens the first time.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I don't know what to say about that. I've run it on two PCs and it worked as I described above in both situations.

Comment: Your code does not run in my machine running Kali Linux. I got few errors. After I fixed them and came back to your question, I guessed your goal is not feasible. By goal I mean what you wrote previously: *which potentially involves updating elements in the Tkinter GUI*. But even if I know there will never be a solution to your problem, I upvoted your question.